# use rviz in another laptop

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to do i use the HOKUYO laser scan RVIZ program in the workstation when the another laptop is in the turtle bot is using Ubuntu 12.04 hydro program to run .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143606/use-rviz-in-another-laptop/) by [Rizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/13506/rizwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/13506/rizwan/) on 2014-03-23**:
any doubt please ask i will reply tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out this tutorial about ROS on multiple machines: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1